# Ionic - Call camera again after taking photo?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m working on an app at the moment that required at least 4 pictures are taking. I’m trying to restart the camera every time a picture is taken so they don’t have to click the take picture button again on the app menu. Here is my code so far:

```
startCamera() {
  if(this.pictureList.length >= 4) {
    this.alertController.create({
      title: this.singleton.TITLE_ERROR,
      message: this.singleton.MESSAGE_TOOMANYPHOTOS,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ok',
        }
      ]
    }).present();
    return;
  }

  let imageData = "";
  this.camera.getPicture(this.options).then((imageData) => {
    this.pictureList.push(imageData);

    let temp = [];
    for (let i of this.pictureList) i && temp.push(i);

    this.pictureList = temp;
    this.slides.refresh();
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

However, the camera does not restart back into the camera? Is there any reason why this wouldn’t work? I’m thinking it’s do to with a me trying to call a function inside of a promise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with **recursion** you can do it, I leave you an unproven example, but that can logically serve you:

I did the example based on an application that saves it in Base 64, but applying the push in a list, as you require it.

```
pictureList: any[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pictureList = null;
    this.optionsCamera = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: this._camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this._camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this._camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };
    this.optionsGallery = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: this._camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: this._camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    };
  }

  startCamera(): void {
    if (this.pictureList.length <= 4) {
      console.log('Open in length: ' + this.pictureList.length);
      this.getPhoto(this.optionsCamera);
      this.startCamera();
    }
  }

  getPhoto(options): void {
    this._camera.getPicture(options).then(
      imageData => {
        let base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        this.pictureList.push(base64Image);
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Could not open the camera: " + err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi, this solution was almost right, I've just done a bit of adjusting and it turns out putting the recursion before I refreshed the slides worked well. Thank you for help leading me to solving this.